# Multistep Markov Chain Problem

Tags: self-study, markov-process

Let's say there is a machine whose condition at the start of every week can be modeled by a Markov Chain and the condition can be categorized as low, medium, high, failed. I will denote the state of the machine as $X$ where $X_n$ is the state at the start of week $n$. The transition matrix $P$ is as follows (the order is low, medium, high, failed):

$\begin{bmatrix}0.9 & 0.05 & 0.03 & 0.02\\0 & 0.85 & 0.09 & 0.06\\0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0.1\\1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

For instance, a machine in the medium state has a probability of 0.09 and 0.06 of being in the high or failed state, respectively, at the start of the next week (it cannot, by itself, go
to the low state).

My questions are

1. What is the probability that a machine has at least one failure three weeks after it is new?
2. On average, how many weeks per year is the machine working?

Just in case you need the multistep transition matrices, I have calculated second-step and third-step matrices in python:

```
matrix([[0.83  , 0.0875, 0.0585, 0.024 ],
        [0.06  , 0.7225, 0.1575, 0.06  ],
        [0.1   , 0.    , 0.81  , 0.09  ],
        [0.9   , 0.05  , 0.03  , 0.02  ]])
```

```
matrix([[0.771   , 0.115875, 0.085425, 0.0277  ],
        [0.114   , 0.617125, 0.208575, 0.0603  ],
        [0.18    , 0.005   , 0.732   , 0.083   ],
        [0.83    , 0.0875  , 0.0585  , 0.024   ]])
```

Comment: @Stijn Although that's a good characterization of the English statement of the problem, notice that the transition matrix as given has no absorbing state.

Comment: @StijnDeVuyst self-study tag added and I agree with whuber that the machine doesn't get stuck in the failed state and it just gets "fixed" and goes back to the low state.

Comment: @whuber: sorry I was too fast with the comment. You are right, it is NOT an absorbing chain and all states communicate with each other. My mistake.

Comment: @StijnDeVuyst Do you know how I can get started with the first problem?

Comment: For the first question, you will need to compute the so-called first-passage time distribution from state 1 (low) to state 4 (failed). The asked probability is $f_{14}^{(1)}+f_{14}^{(2)}+f_{14}^{(3)}$ where $f_{14}^{(n)}$ is the probability that the machine will be in state 4 in week $n$ *for the first time*. There is a recursive set of equations that will give you these probabilities. The second question is easier: this is  the sum of equilibrium probabilities that the machine is in state 1, 2 or 3. These follow by solving the set of equilibrium equations.

Comment: Sometimes it’s easier to simulate an N=100,000 observation sample from the fitted model and compute any quantity of interest (e.g. time to first …) from the simulated data.  This avoids recursive computations.

Answer (score 1):

For the second question:
Define a row vector $s$ = [1 0 0 0] for the initial status. Calculate $z_{i}=s\times P^i$, where $i$ = 1, 2, ... up to 52 (since a year has 52 weeks), and $P$ is the transition matrix. Each of $z_{i}$ is a row vector of 4 elements. Denote the fourth element of $z_{i}$ as $z_{i}(4)$. The average number of weeks in a year the machine works is $n = 52-\sum_{i=1}^{52} z_i(4)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I agree with you in regard to the first question but for the second one, don't you think we actually need to calculate the steady-state behavior of the system?

Comment: Since this Markov Chain is an irreducible and recurrent set, I will have a vector $m$ and set it to $mP = m$ where $P$ is the transition matrix and solve the set of equilibrium equations. What do you think about this way?

Comment: @Jasonli1997: You can easily find the probabilities of steady state, denoted as $m$, such that $mP=m$. However, I cannot see how is this steady state related to your second question. Among the 52 weeks of a year, the probabilities in the first multiple weeks are quite different from those of the steady state. To get the average number of working weeks, I think we should "average" them over all 52 weeks.

Comment: @Jasonli1997: Let me explain a little bit more. It can be verified that the probabilities of stead state is $m$ = [0.4918    0.1639    0.2951    0.0492]. So the failure probability of steady state is 0.0492. If this is true for all of the 52 weeks in a year, then the average number of weeks that the machine fails to work is 52*0.0492. However, in most of the 52 weeks, the failure probability is less then 0.0492. For instance, $z_{1}(4)$ = 0.02; $z_{2}(4)$ = 0.024; .... Thus, what we should do is to add $z_{i}(4)$ together for $i$ from 1 up to 52 to get the average number of weeks of failure.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense @user295357 thank you

Comment: I really don't think this answer to the first question is correct. Computing the asked probability this way yields 0.0700145, while computed using first-passage time probabilities, the probability that the machine fails within 3 weeks is 0.0713. The latter result seems to be corroborated by a quick simulation. The answer by user295357 is wrong because it assumes that the events of failing in week 1, 2 and 3 respectively are independent, while they are not.

Comment: @StijnDeVuyst: Thanks for your comment. At this moment I don't know how did you get your result of 0.0713 from your expression of $f_{14}^{(1)}+f_{14}^{(2)}+f_{14}^{(3)}$. Could you please provide these values of $f_{14}^{(i)}$ so that I can understand your method better ?

Answer (score 1):

Let us call $T_{14}$ the first-passage time from state 1 to state 4. If the chain starts in $X_0=1$, then $T_{14}$ is the number of steps until the chain reaches state 4 *for the first time*. That means for $n>0$ that $T_{14}=n$ if and only if $X_0=1$, $X_1\neq 4$, ..., $X_{n-1}\neq 4$ and finally $X_n=4$. Let the distribution of this
first-passage time $T_{14}$ be given by the probabilities
$$
  f_{14}^{(n)} = \text{Prob}[T_{14}=n]\,, n>0\,,
$$
which can be computed recursively by conditioning on the first step $X_1$. That is,
$$
  f_{14}^{(n)} = \sum_{k\in\{1,2,3\}} p_{1k} f_{k4}^{(n-1)}
$$
where $p_{ij}$ are the transition probabilities in the matrix $\mathbf{P}$ given in the original post. Particularly note that transitions to the failed state 4 are not counted here because we only consider the event where that happens for the first time at time step $n$ and not before. Starting from $f_{k4}^{(1)}=p_{k4}$, $k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$, these probabilities can be computed up to whatever time step $n$ you need. For a full explanation on first-passage times and how their distribution can recursively be computed, see for example [here](http://courses.washington.edu/inde411/MarkovChains(part4).pdf).

Now, your **first question** asks: what is the probability that the machine fails in the first three weeks if it starts as new? This happens if and only if $T_{14}\leqslant 3$, so
$$
  \text{Prob}[T_{14}\leqslant 3] =  f_{14}^{(1)} + f_{14}^{(2)}  + f_{14}^{(3)} 
$$
My R-code for doing this gives 0.0713:

```
P <- matrix(c(0.9,0.05,0.03,0.02,
              0,  0.85,0.09,0.06,
              0,  0,   0.9, 0.1,
              1,  0,   0,   0    ),4,4,byrow=TRUE)
N <- 3          # number of weeks
fto4 <- matrix(rep(0,9),3,N)
fto4[,1] <- P[1:3,4]
for (n in 2:N) {
  for (i in 1:3) {
    fto4[i,n] <- P[i,1:3] %*% fto4[1:3,n-1]
  }
}
sum(fto4[1,])   ## 0.0713
```

The following does a Monte Carlo estimation of that probability using $10^7$ replications and gives a 95%-confidence interval:

```
R <- 10000000   # number of replications in MC simulation
count <- 0
for (r in 1:R) {
  X <- c(1,rep(0,N))   # state of machine in subsequent weeks
  for (n in 1:N) { X[n+1] <- sample(1:4,1,prob=P[X[n],]) }
  if (max(X)==4) {count <- count+1}   # count if there was a failure in N weeks
}
fail.MC <- count/R
CI <- fail.MC + qnorm(0.975)*sqrt(fail.MC*(1-fail.MC)/R)*c(-1,+1); CI
## CI is [0.07119456,0.07151364]
```

The following is how this is computed in the answer of user295357:

```
p0 <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0),1,4)
p1 <- p0 %*% P
p2 <- p1 %*% P
p3 <- p2 %*% P
1-(1-p1[1,4])*(1-p2[1,4])*(1-p3[1,4])  ## 0.0700145
```

This is admittedly close but not the same. This value is also far outside the confidence interval given by the simulation.

I do however agree with the solution of the **second question** *if* you interpret that question as asking for the expected number of weeks *of the first year* in which the machine is working.
In my opinion however, the question does not mention any particular year so it would be safe to assume it concerns a year during the steady-state (equilibrium) operation of the machine. That would be $52(1-\pi_4)=49.44262$.